# How to show contents with punctuation in columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got a DataGrid which refuses to display data when columns have punctuation. I've got the following SQL statement which places the resulting data in a DataTable:

```
string statement = "SELECT TOP 200 [Test] AS [Primary key for Department records.] FROM [dbo].[Children]";

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(statement, connection))
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dtResults);
                        }
```

Due to the `.` character in the alias, the DataGrid does not display the information contained within the DataTable.  I have discovered this through trial and error. How can I get the datagrid to display the data with such a column?

This is the binding code:

```
dgResults.DataContext = myDataTable.AsDataView();
dgResults.AutoGeneratingColumn += new EventHandler<DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs>(dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn);
dgResults.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   //Sets the DataGrid's headers to be TextBlocks, which solves a problem whereby underscore characters in the header are ignored.
   TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
   block.Text = e.Column.Header.ToString();
   e.Column.Header = block;
}
```

Comment: How are you filling your DataTable? Can you show that code please?

Comment: Sure @Dilshod just a sec

Comment: @Dilshod - Added above

Comment: Do you really need that .(dot)? [Primary key for Department records.]

Comment: Yes @Dilshod as this is just an example. I've got hundreds of columns all with punctuation in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this works, but try:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(statement, connection))
{
      adapter.Fill(dset);
}
DataTable dtResults = dset.Tables[0];
```

I hope that solves the problem.

UPDATE:
Try to get rid of punctuations.

```
       //this is just a list of punctuations. Database field never might not contains some of them. 
       string[] punct = new string[]{"[", "]" ,"(", ")", "{", "}", "<", ">", ":",
            ",", "-", "...", "!", "«", "»", "-", ".", "?", "\"", "'",  "'", ";", "/"};

        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            string colName = column.ColumnName;
            bool b = punct.Any(s => colName.Contains(s));
            var listOfPunct = punct.Where(s => colName.Contains(s)).ToList();
            foreach (string p in listOfPunct)
            {
                colName = colName.Replace(p, "");
            }
            column.ColumnName = colName;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Dilshod, that's just what i needed!